Failed to deploy docker built on google build
I am trying to create a build trigger to deploy a docker file but I am having the following error message


Failed to trigger build: generic::invalid_argument: if
'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a)
specify 'build.logs_bucket', (b) use the REGIONAL_USER_OWNED_BUCKET
build.options.default_logs_bucket_behavior option, or (c) use either
CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY / NONE logging options


In my old project I could specify service account to none and that solved the issue however looks like that google now is requiring it and since I have a dockerfile I can not specify the
options:
logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
As it is required in the cloudbuild.yaml since I am using a dockerfile, how to solve this issue ?
